# IF Function Condition in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, lets say I want to check if from A1 to A9 is equal to the value 10? How do I do it?

All I could think of is:

```
IF(A1:A9 = 10, "True", "False")
```

So what should I do to fix this?

Edit:
Since my question wasn't clear just now. I just want to know like...

```
IF(A1 = 10, True, False)
IF(A2 = 10, True, False)
IF(A3 = 10, True, False)
```

and so on...

Comment: Just try `=A1=10`

Answer (score 1):

For single cells to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` just type `=A1=10` and drag down.

For your whole range at once, just try:

```
{=AND(EXACT(A1:A9;10))}
```

Notice it's an array formula entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if any cell in `A1:A9` contains a "10" using `=CountIf()`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A9, 10)>0, "True", "False")
```

If, instead, you wanted to know if the range summed to 10, you could stick `Sum()` in there (it's not clear from your question):

```
=IF(Sum(A1:A9)=10, "True", "False")
```

Comment: The true and false don't have to be in quotes as excel recognizes them as 1 & 0.

Comment: Right, but then the `If()` isn't needed as boolean logic works fine in excel: `=Countif(A1:A9, 10)>0` will suffice. I assume that OP is wanting to more than just spit out `True` or `False` though.

Comment: That's a good example, learnt something :) thanks. But I get the feeling the OP is "out to lunch"... Ah well, at least i got something.

Answer (score 0):

Checks whether the amount of cells equal to 10 are equal to amount of cells inside `A1:A10`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A9, 10) = ROWS(A1:A9), TRUE, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice screencap.

Comment: @ThomasKimber funnily enough, captured via [PowerPoint recording tool](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/record-your-screen-in-powerpoint-0b4c3f65-534c-4cf1-9c59-402b6e9d79d0)  :)

Comment: Very nice! I did not know you could do that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want all cells to be equal to 10, or any one cell to be equal, but here goes:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A9,10)=COUNT(A1:A9),TRUE,FALSE)
```

will show true if **all** values are 10.

This version will show if any one of the cells is equal to 10:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A9,10)>=1,TRUE,FALSE)
```